# Rs-485 isolation

Tags: power-electronics, isolation, rs485, circuit-protection

[image]

Hi, 
I have RS485 communication circuit as shown in figure. But it has no isolation, only SM712 is used for ESD protection. Now, i think it will be better to isolate the it.So, how can i isolate it? so, should i replace the RS485 (SN65HVD20D) by a internally isolated RS 485 or have to use some isolators in the circuit to isolate it?

If I use a bi-directional digital isolator (say ISO1540), can it possible to isolate the bus side A and B? Can I exactlty want to know what would be the problem if I do so? Please go through the block diagram below:

[image]

Comment: That's a bit broad. Obviously, if you have an isolated replacement of your transceiver, that'll come with a datasheet or example board with a schematic of how to use it.

Comment: "I think it will be better": Why do you think it is? "I think" doesn't sound like proper engineering; you will have a reasoning, and that reasoning is probably critical for how to design your circuit!

Comment: @Marcus Müller, But if i want isolate my circuit, how can i do that without replacing the RS485 IC?

Comment: In general, getting an isolated transceiver means you get stuck with that supplier and they tend to be expensive. When there's an industry standard for SOIC8 RS485 transceivers with plenty of second source. So in general I would consider using a separate isolator. These are more reliable than optocouplers: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/digital-isolators-protect-rs232-bus.html

Comment: OK. If i use isolator (say digital isolator), where should i place this, on Input side of RS485 (Pin A and B) or on output side( RO and DI pin)?

Comment: Get an NXE1S0303MC and an SI8622 with default levels suitable for RS485 and isolate the entire transceiver.

Comment: @Jeroen3, So in this case, if i apply my isolation on the output side of the RS485 (on RO and DI pin) can i connect the DE or /RE directly to controller? Or this pins is also needs isolation? or it will be better to isolate on input side?

Comment: You cannot isolated the bus side A and B. You should isolate the other logic side, I see you need 4 signals for this, see Si864x.

Comment: SN65HVD20D work with 5V (4.5V minimum)

Comment: @ jeroen3, ok. But is ADUM series suitable for RS485 isolation?Because at present we have ADUM1201 In our lab. So, using 2 ADUM1201 can it be possible to isolate?Or should I go for 4 channel in ADUM Series? Or Si864x would be better?

Comment: @Jeroen3, If I use a bi-directional digital isolator (say ISO1540), can it possible to isolate the bus side A and B? Can I exactlty want to know what would be the problem if I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can isolate the lines going to the transceiver, or you can isolate the RS-485.

**Isolated transceiver:**
[image]

**Isolator + Transceiver:**
[image]

Typically there is less choice in bus-to-bus isolators or combined transceiver/isolator chips, thus I commonly isolate CAN bus with abundant generic logic isolators and a separate transceiver, bonus point is BOM re-use. 
There seems to be more available for RS-485 though.

However, if you're not looking for low maintenance longevity, the isolated transceiver should be fine.

Image sources:
https://forums.parallax.com/discussion/162277/isolated-rs-485
https://www.radiolocman.com/review/article.html?di=336193

[This is how the isolator work](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/digital-isolators-protect-rs232-bus.html) when you do not use old school optocouplers.

Comment: I have understood the above to methods. But what will be the problem if I isolate in the bus side with a bidirectional isolator? Isn't possible? I have post the image below.

Comment: @AakashDey you cannot isolate the RS-485 side with any random digital isolator. RS-485 is a differential standard with particular voltage levels while a normal digital isolator deals with single-ended signals.

Comment: @AakashDey Research the signal levels used by RS-485.

Comment: OK. I will study on this. Thanks for the guidance and help.